# Look up a value in another sheets column and add value from that row to it

Tags: excel-formula

So here is what I like to do. I would like to look up if these email addresses (Image 1) are present in column C from another sheet (Image 2). If it is present I would like to have the "Name" and "Address" from that sheet to be placed in column B and C in the first sheet.

What formula should I use here?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4FdW.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMc6S.png)

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$C:$C,0)),"")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have newer version of Excel (Excel 365 or Excel 2021), you can use the function XLOOKUP. Link to Microsoft Page [about the XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)

The formula in your case would look like this:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,"not found")
```

You give it value you search ("A2"), in which column it will search (C:C on Sheet2) and from which column it will return the results (A:A Sheet2). The "not found" part is a custom string I set up for cases when searched value is not found in the list)

[image]